# Adjacent JButtons

Tags: java, jbutton, grid-layout

I am creating a word game where letters must be chosen from a 6X6 grid. However, only adjacent letters can be chosen(ie. adjacent buttons). What way is there of identifying that buttons are adjacent to each other?

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this including having a 2D array of JButton and simply testing a JButton's neighbors. Rather than ask for code, at this stage you're far better off experimenting on your own first, and only then if stuck, come back with your code attempt and more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to represented buttons in 2-dimensional table, like:

```
Button[][] x;
```

(size of rows / columns depends on your requirements)

Adjacent buttons to `x[i][j]` will be:

```
x[i-1][j]
x[i+1][j]
x[i][j-1]
x[i][j+1]
```

Additionally you need to check that index doesn't go out of the bounds, i.e. it cannot be less the 0 or bigger then size of table.